# Angular Universal: Node/Javascript Memory heap still failing after upping max_old_space_size

Tags: node.js, angular-universal, nrwl, nomachine-nx

For some reason, even after changing `max_old_space_size` to 8192 I am still getting the error that:

```
FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

```
"start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 && nx run zeta-frontend:serve-ssr",
```

This is what my command looks like ^

Notes:

1. Using nrwl nx might have to do with. Not sure. However, it is erroring out at around the default of 1.6gb.
2. Left a sister github issue for this one: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/14054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Was able to solve via the following:

1.

```
"ng": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/ng",
"nx": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/nx",
"start:serve": "npm run nx -- run zeta-frontend:serve",
```

2. Being that angular universal makes a large initial bundle on serve, it would cause the development bundle to fail silently unless budget was updated. By doing the following:

```
"budgets": [
  {
    "type": "initial",
    "maximumWarning": "20mb",
    "maximumError": "40mb"
  },
 ...
]
```

It allowed the angular universal build to pass.

^ feel free to try above if have the same problem